# How to render template through route without any frameworks

Tags: php, html, routes

I am creating a basic routing system for a bespoke CMS and I am wanting to do this completely in raw PHP without frameworks. So far, I have the routing down, with GET and POST methods working correctly.

Here is my index.php file

```php
 <?php
include_once 'Request.php';
include_once 'Router.php';
$router = new Router(new Request);
$router->get('/', function() {
  return <<<HTML
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
HTML;
});
$router->get('/profile', function($request) {
    return <<<HTML
    <h1>Profile</h1>
  HTML;
});
$router->get('/data', function($request) {
  return json_encode($request->getBody());
});
```

As you can see, for the routes '/' and '/profile' I am returning some HTML code using heredoc. This is okay but will eventually fill up this file really quickly.

Is there a way to render a template (from inside a subfolder for example) in the space of the 'return `html code`'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your second parameter for the get method is a callback function that will be triggered in the function if the route matches? If that's the case I don't see why you return the HTML as it isn't used anywhere. You might want to echo() or print() instead.
If you want to return the code and output it later, you need to save the return value into a variable.
No matter which path you choose, you could use another include() and just put the relevant code into a separate file for each path if you want to make your main script more readable.

I'd also recommend to use require_once instead of include_once in the top as there's no point in continuing execution if these class files are missing.

Comment: Nice one! This was better and worked great, thank you!

The reason for the return was for the output into the DOM but as you said, this wasn't needed.